# How to embed text into cucumber report with ruby?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, page-object-gem

How to embed the text into the cucumber report using ruby. We can do it using java by using the below code but similarly how can I do it in cucumber-ruby?

I have tried using embed method but it is not working.

Below is the code in java to write text in to report.

Source: https://gist.github.com/aslakhellesoy/4072962

```java
import cucumber.api.Scenario;

public class MyStepdefs {
    private Scenario scenario;

    @Before
    public void before(Scenario scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    @Given("^I have (\\d+) cukes in my belly$")
    public void cukes_in_my_belly(int cukes) {
        scenario.write("This goes into the report(s)\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution it is simply by printing the value as below:

```rb
Given("I have {int} cukes in my belly") do |cukes|
 puts 'This goes into the report: #{cukes}'
end
```